# VSCode Python SSH - Debug aborted without errors or warnings

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, ssh, exit

I am developing an application on a remote server.
I'm using Python and am connected via ssh with the specific extension.
I start debugging and everything seems to proceed normally but suddenly debugging stops and there is no reason (error or warning).

Can anyone suggest me where to look for the reason or how to trace the problem?
The script, executed outside VSCode, runs smoothly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

in the end I found a possible cause and, therefore, the solution.
There is a problem with the sequence of imports and module import for MariaDB.  By moving this import to the head, the problem was solved.